# Difference between capturing and bubbling events

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events, event-bubbling

Please tell me difference b/w

Capturing and Bubbling events.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event Capturing vs Event Bubbling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661199/event-capturing-vs-event-bubbling)

Comment: Have a crack at this: http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html this article has it pretty clearly outlined. Googled it for you in a few seconds.