# Get Attribute Javascript - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have the following HTML :

```
<label>
    <input type='checkbox' checked="checked" />
    CLICK ME....
</label>
```

and script :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("label").on("click",function(){
        if ($(this).children("input[type='checkbox']").is(':checked'))
        {
            //alert("checked");
           // return false;
        }
        else

        {
           // alert("not checked");
              // return false;        
        }
    });
});
```

How can i get the checked state ? If its checked i want to perform some operations other ways some other .

I used Live/On because the contend is dynamically added.

Please check this [jSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5N7cW/)

Comment: tutorial here: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2008/12/how-to-check-if-checkbox-is-checked.html

Comment: @scubaFLY Thank you ,but i am failed to use `.is`,`.attr`,`.prop` methods...thats why i put a question.

Comment: @DileepDil i see your code is working well.......

Comment: Which jQuery version do you use?

Comment: @BartekR 1.7....also pls check the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5N7cW/10/

Comment: You should not wrap the `input` with the `label` as it can trigger an extra `click`.

Comment: @BartekR His jsFiddle example uses jQUery 1.7.1

Comment: @Stefan i think that i can prevent that by using `return false;`

Comment: use the  `for` attribute of `label` wisely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried this and worked (jQuery 1.7.1):

```
<label>
    <input type='checkbox' checked="checked" />
    CLICK ME....
</label>
<div id="result"></div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("label").live("click",function(){
        var elem = $(this).children("input[type='checkbox']");

        $('#result').html('prop: ' + elem.prop('checked'));
    });
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tNGqs/

**UPDATE:** After your comments I've created second jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8ByqX/

As I understand you want to get rid of firing event on child element. You should define stop propagation on element:

```
$(value).click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Look also at Hello71's comment on accepted answer here:

[How to check for a click in a parent element, but not in the child?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170897/how-to-check-for-a-click-in-a-parent-element-but-not-in-the-child)

Answer (score 0):

Found your solution:

HTML:

```
<label>
    <input type='checkbox' checked="checked" />
    CLICK ME....
</label>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("label").change(function(){
        alert($(this).children("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked'));
    });
});
```

alerts the current state.

[working demo 3 with label as parent of input](http://jsfiddle.net/scubafly/UHbNs/3/)

Comment: please take a look at the Question.

Comment: not sure if you want to check the state after the onclick event? but otherwise you could use the .each() function as @erimerturk is suggesting. What do you want to do?

Comment: i need the current state : when i click i need the current state.

Comment: This is the theory ,but sometimes this simpleness will destruct our time ,Please see this jsfiddle [pardon me if i cant express the real problem] http://jsfiddle.net/5N7cW/12/  Pleasee try to click on that label instead of checkbox ,the problem when we click on label we need to triger the change to input but when we click on input it automatically triger the click

Comment: hmm I see the problem. But labels are not used this way see [link](http://www.10sharpdesign.com/accessibility/forms/3b-ii-labels-checkboxes.html) and then you could use an change() on the checkbox to trigger instead of the on click

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6342/discussion-between-scubafly-and-dileep-dil)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("label").click(function(){
        if ($(this).children("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked")
        {
            //alert("checked");
           // return false;
        }
        else

        {
           // alert("not checked");
              // return false;        
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: .prop("checked") was added in later versions of jquery (1.6+ I think)

Answer (score 0):

```
     $("label").on("click",function(){

    $.each($(this).children("input[type='checkbox']"), function(index, value){

     if ($(value).is(':checked'))
            {
                //alert("checked");
               // return false;
            }else
            {
            }
    }) 
});
```

Comment: Thank you ,But pls check the updated jsfiddle ,try to click on that `label` http://jsfiddle.net/5N7cW/12/

Answer (score 0):

works with latest jQuery **v (1.7)**

**TIP :** use `for` attribute wisely.. see the **[`for in label`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/label)**

#### HTML

```
<input type='checkbox' id="mycheckbox"/>
<label for="mycheckbox"> CLICK ME....</label>
```

#### javascript

```
  $('input[type=checkbox]').on('click',function() {
        var checkboxStatus = $(this).prop('checked');
        alert(checkboxStatus);
        if(checkboxStatus)
        {
            alert('now checkbox is checked');
        } 
        else
        {
            alert('now checkbox is unchecked');
        } 
    });
```

[`working DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/nqyQh/)

Comment: This one is working ,But the HTML markup is incorrect [Please see my question `input` is inside the `label1`]

Comment: you have used wrong way. by my markup style you can check the checkbox by click on text too.. this is what `for` attribute  is used for

Comment: You should not use `$('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked');` within the event handler to access the current element. `$(this).prop('checked')` or even `this.checked` is better. http://jsfiddle.net/Ud9Gt/

Comment: @Stefan : yes your are right. I have updated my answer. but keeping in `var` is better way

Comment: @DileepDil : I dint write such a crap code. what wrong with my solution. you must need to change the place of `label`

Comment: Prdon me diEcho ,Your solution works well ,But i cant make two answers[I know it ,but stackoverflow need a rethink about this].

Answer (score 0):

```
$("label").on("click",function(e){

    if($(this).find(":checkbox").prop("checked"))
    {
     alert("checked now...now make it unchecked");
       $(this) .children("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked",false);
    }
    else{
    alert("not checked");
         $(this) .children("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked",true);
    }
e.preventDefault();   

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5N7cW/21/

Comment: Please check this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5N7cW/19/ ,the else part is not working...