# How can the children listen/capture to the parent's event

Tags: javascript, html, dom, jquery-events

How can the parent fire the custom event to notify its children/siblings?
For example:

```
<div id="div1">
   <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

`div2` had `addEventListener('customEvent2', doSth)`, and then `div1` will fire a custom event (`customEvnet2`), but this will never trigger div2's `doSth` function.

Sample code:  http://jsfiddle.net/r4tcT/2/

The "div 1 trigger customEvent 2" button never works

so when a parent fire a custom event (dispatchEvent[IE9]/fireEvent[IE9-]/trigger[jQuery]), the children can not capture the event.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: I believe that this is not possible, unless you make some kind of hack, because events going up on the DOM tree like bubbles and never going down to children

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference you are talking about is either between the 'Capturing' event model or the 'Bubbling' event model. jQuery's trigger operates on the Bubble model probably because this is the more supported event model -- mainly thanks to Internet Explorer. The Bubble model only travels backwards up through an elements parents... this is the reason why your events don't trigger on `div2` when fired from `div1`, as it is always bubbling up and not down.

I've not tried custom events before with native functions but most modern browsers allow for you to decide which type of model you use when you set the event listener:

```
addEventListener (type, listener[, useCapture])
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener

Basically if you use `true` as the final argument the event listener should trigger in the Capture phase *(which is when the event is travelling down the dom tree)*. If set to false the event will trigger in the bubbling phase which occurs when travelling back up the dom tree.

This has been discussed here:

[Event Capturing vs Event Bubbling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661199/event-capturing-vs-event-bubbling)

As I've said whether this will work for bespoke events I'm not sure. I am pretty certain you can not do this with jQuery *(as of yet)* probably due to the lack of support in older browsers.

### **Correction**

It appears what I guessed at above doesn't work. I thought as much due to the term 'Capturing' kind of makes you think about capturing user input -- and when bespoke events are involved there is no way to define a new kind of user input. So with that in mind I put together this quick jQuery plugin... it's only been roughly tested, but the logic should be sound - hope it's useful:

```
/**
 * unbubble v0.2
 *
 * trigger an event down through the children of a collection, 
 * rather than up through it's parents
 *
 *  @update 2013/03/18 - fixed the problem of triggering bubble phase each
 *    step down the element tree as pointed out by @vine.
 */
$.fn.unbubble = function( eventNames ){
  var names = eventNames.split(' '), 
      non = names.length, 
      args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  /// our own trigger function designed to bubble down... not up!
  var trigger = function(){
    var i, events, elm = $(this);
    /// make sure we can read the events array
    if ( $._data ) {
      /// make sure events is defined
      if ( (events = $._data(this, 'events')) ) {
        /// do a quick check, saves firing trigger on every element found
        for ( i=0; i<non; i++ ) {
          /// make sure our eventName appears in the event list
          if ( names[i] && ( names[i] in events ) ) {
            /// trigger the standard jQuery trigger function
            elm.triggerHandler.apply(elm, args);
            /// escape as trigger should fire for multiple names
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    /// if we can't access the events array, just trigger and hope
    else {
      /// trigger the standard jQuery trigger function
      elm.triggerHandler.apply(elm, args);
    }
    /// trigger for all the children, and on, and on...
    elm.children().each(trigger);
  };
  /// foreach element trigger now...
  this.each(trigger);
}

/**
 * Example usage
 */
$(function(){
  /// bind our event as usual
  $('.div2').bind('customEvent', function(){
    alert('I should trigger!');
  });
  /// rather than use trigger, fire with unbubble
  $('#div1').unbubble( 'customEvent' );
});
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but according to w3c, using addEventListener with the 3rd param as true will do the capture phase for the event, however, i have update the code without using the jQuery( here is new code http://jsfiddle.net/EDjqu/4/), but it seems like the capture phase is still not working

Comment: Yep I just realise this myself... thought I should test it out as I didn't know if it would or not... that led me to build a quick jQuery plugin instead.

Comment: thanks, i think i got no choice except looping through the children , same as @haynar comment on the post

Comment: No worries at all.. :) one thing I will say though is that haynar's solution is hardcoded to specific identifiers & involves having to set `customEvent2` on `div1` - not ideal *(as he admits)* - I wouldn't recommend that you do that *(unless you are only implementing these event listeners as a one off)*. The above plugin is genralised to work in exactly the same way `$().trigger` does with regard to supporting any events, passing extra paramters, and can handle any distance between parent & descendant... which will keep your code neater, easier to manage, & more inline with jQuery's ethos.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of pebbl is good but it has flaw. The capturing phase is somehow simulated by the normal triggering of events from document down to the concerned element. But the issue will be, calling the standard jQuery trigger function on any element will immediately followed by a bubbling phase starting from that element and up. So i believe he can stick with accessing the events data directly from the collection of elements and calling it directly not using the standard trigger function , something like this

```
var JQ_LT_17 = parseFloat($.fn.jquery) < 1.7;

function getEventsData(element) {
        return JQ_LT_17 ? $(element).data('events') : $._data(element).events;
}
```

Code snippet borrowed form jQuery.bind-first library v0.1 Vladimir Zhuravlev

Comment: +1 Very good point - totally didn't think of that - I'll need to make a modification when I get a second :)

Answer (score 0):

`customEvent2` is only bound to `div2`.  When you try to trigger it on `div1`, nothing happens because that event doesn't exist for `div1`.

If you want to fire `customEvent2`, it has to be triggered on an element (or child of one) it is actually bound to.

Comment: this is exactly what i dont want it, for example i have div2_a, div2_b, div2_c .....and maybe lot more, then i have to go through all the div2 in case to fire the event

Answer (score 0):

I have played a little bit with the code and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/r4tcT/4/) is what I now have. It is a hack, but maybe it could help you to solve your problem?