# Is there a way to register a low-level js event that could never be stopped from bubbling?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, stoppropagation

Is there a way to register a low-level js event that could never be stopped from bubbling?

I'm constructing a base-class that should always receive `onclick` event. The problem is that child class could use `e.stopPropagating()` which effectively cuts my base `onclick` behavior.

Is there a way to be able to receive `onclick` event in base-class independently of what people can (over)write in child class?

Comment: Behaviour you described violates event driven model. If such behaviour could exists you simply can't expect anything from your application to be 100% true if you using listeners.

Comment: Only way you can do something like that is by assigning listener before child got `stopPropagation` listener. This is really hard to implement and not always possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Real world example where event capturing is necessary / preferred?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24786769/real-world-example-where-event-capturing-is-necessary-preferred)