# Event bubbling vs capturing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

What is the best way to explain difference between event bubbling and event capturing? Which is a more efficient option? I am working through a jQuery example online. It led me to wonder if they are mutually exclusive, or if it's just a matter of preference.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661199/event-capturing-vs-event-bubbling